# Character \x92 error in MySQL from webhook

Tags: mysql, webhooks

I get a SQL exception in my Spring Boot application saying `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x92s.","...' for column 'json' at row 1`. This most likely means that I am getting data from the webhook as latin-1 or Windows 1252. I do see two types of apostrophe's, the `'` and the `’`. My database is set up as `utf8mb4`.

I find this a bit strange because I used to get the error the other way around. How can I check in which encoding the data is sent? / How can I solve this problem?

The webhook is from Typeform. When I send a test request via "test webhook" I see all kinds of `\u2019` and similar codes when I look at the response header tab in Chrome Dev Tools. So this has to be unicode. I am a bit confused why MySQL interpets this as latin-1.

When I print out the string on the backend before saving it I see it's in unicode. Why? Because of the following: the word `collega's` is written as `\x63\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x67\x65\x61\x27\x73` in unicode [(see a converter here)](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode) which is `99 111 108 108 101 103 97 39 115` in decimal. This is what I get back. The `’` is `\xe2\x80\x99` or in decimal `226 128 153`.

When I debug the `Mysql.IO.class` I see that the character encoding is `WINDOWS-1252`. That is the culprit but where is this set? Hmm... somehow the JDBC driver does this at the following code in `Connectionimpl.class`.

```
String encoding = null;
if (this.getUseUnicode()) {
  encoding = this.getEncoding();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... the issue was that in my dev build I didn't specify the character encoding in the URL. However, I did do this in my production build. This is why it was working in production and not in development.

I needed to add the query parameters from my production environment which were: `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`.

Comment: Awesome Melvin! Glad you found an issue. Please mark you question as answered :)

Comment: Thanks, apologies for first assuming there might be an issue with typeform. Though, I did put a much higher probability that it was just me. Using IntelliJ/IDEA and its  debugger really helped pinning it down.